# Implementing onClick in the Recyclerview Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

1. I would like to know how to implement onClick for each item in my
   grid (using Recycler View and Card view) to launch a new
   activity.Below is my ViewHolder class and the RecyclerView Adapter
   Class

   This is my RecyclerView Adapter Class

   ```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.nfc.Tag;
   import android.nfc.TagLostException;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import java.util.List;

   public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

       private List<ItemObject> itemList;
       private Context context;

       public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
           this.itemList = itemList;
           this.context = context;
       }

       @Override
       public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

           View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
           RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
           return rcv;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
           holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
           holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
           holder.countryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"This is Maps",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return this.itemList.size();
       }
   }

   //This is my Recycler View Holder Class


   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

       public TextView countryName;
       public ImageView countryPhoto;

       public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
           countryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
           countryPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       }
   }
   ```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: why have you added  a click listener in view holder ?

Answer (score 4):

I use Interface as the Callback to handle this case.

First, I create an interface class inside Adapter.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<ItemObject> itemList;
    private Context context;
    private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    public void addItemClickListener(ItemClickListener listener) {
        mItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
        holder.countryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    //Define your Interface method here
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Then, let's the Activity or Fragment implement that Interface and add the listener.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
    implements RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    private List<ItemObject> mItemList;
    ...
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
       //Make sure mItemList not NULL
       RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mItemList);
       //Add Item Click listener
       adapter.addItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {   
        Toast.makeText(.getContext(),"Click on item: " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for for the Answers..Yeah They will work for me

Comment: Beautiful! First time using interface and this was simple to follow unlike many others. Worked excellent in 2023!

Answer (score 0):

your code look like fine, if asking for how to creat intent to open new activity here is whet you should change

it is lazy way **not recommended for best pratice**

make a static variable in your Mian activty witch is hold a refrance some thing like that

```
        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

 public static Activity activity;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

                activity=this;

        }
    }
```

and then inside your click

```
...

          @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(.getContext(),"Click on item: " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.activity, MyOtherActivity.class));
            }

...
```

Comment: Thanks..I will Try it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear from your initial post what your issue is, but if all you want to do is implement an OnClickListener in your `RecyclerViewAdapter`, just add the following:

First, change your class declaration to this:

`public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> implements OnClickListener {`

Then, add your onClick method to the class, to complete the interface.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {   
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Code to change activity goes here." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Finally, you'll need to set an OnClickListener in your adapter class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    holder.countryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, personally I wouldn't do things this way. What I would do instead is add a private inner class to your adapter, like this:

```
private AdapterOnClickListener implements OnClickListener() {
    private String message;

    public AdapterOnClickListener (String toast) {
         message = toast;
    }

    public void onClick (View v) {
       Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),toast ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Then in the adapter you call:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
    holder.setOnClickListener(new AdapterOnClickListener ("Instead of a string, I can be an intent. Then in your listener, you can call (If I recall correctly) getContext().startActivity(intent), and have an activity.");
    holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
    holder.countryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```